# Upgrading from PHP7.4 => PHP8, is it possible to ignore certain errors

Tags: php, error-handling

We have a huge codebase where we ignored the notice from php7 when accessing undefined variables or array-keys.
For example

```
$somethingThatMayNotExist = $_REQUEST['somethingThatMayNotExist']
```

PHP8 now throws an Error. I know that we should always check if the key exists, or if the variable is defined. But the codebase is so big and we have poor unit-test coverage that I would rather switch to php8 and have these errors handled as notices (And setting the value to null).
Is this with somekind of custom error-handler possible? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Simply adding `?? NULL` behind the `$_REQUEST['....']` would get rid of the error in PHP 8. Anyway, it is never a good idea to ignore notices.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I know, but also finding all issues is a very time consuming task and we can't be sure to have found them all (it's not only on $_REQUEST variables)

Comment: I have had a similar problem, and what I did to solve it was. 1. Check the log file and work through all the notices I could find there. 2. Have all new notices and errors send to me by email, and resolve them as soon as they occur. Now my code base is completely notice and error free, and it wasn't that time consuming. Most errors are very basic.

Comment: Great idea. We already do have an error-handler that sends mails on critical errors. I will ignore these errors for now and log them to a specific place where we can refactor them based on occurence.

Comment: You can use regex search and replace, or `sed` search and replace with regexes to replace ALL of your lines with an updated version. Does not matter how big the code base is ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @KikoSoftware'ss comment I solved this issue by creating a custom error-handler and ignored these types of error by logging and consolidating them to be refactored.

```
set_error_handler(array($this,'handleError'))

public function handleError($code, $message, $file, $line)
{
     if(str_contains($message, 'whatever errormessage should be ignored') {
            // TODO: send mail or log error somewhere for further refactoring
            return null; // php7.4-like behaviour
      }
       
      parent::handleError($code, $message, $file, $line);
}
```

Comment: `if($code) == 8192 return null;` and goooooooodbye

Answer (score 1):

I used this regex find and replace:

$_REQUEST[(.+)]

($_REQUEST[$1] ?? "")

Without the outer parenthesis in the replace, the html got messed up in places.

I used Regexxer from the Linux Mint Software Manager to replace in the multiple files. The regex find and replace in Notepadqq doesn't work properly.

Answer (score -2):

php8 create exception on non isset array keys. and you may be create global hook for proccessing this exeptions.

Comment: This is bad advice. First of all, you don't show us how that could be done, but secondly, you don't warn about the fact that someone who does this might miss useful error messages.